# Jquery datepicker it not displaying next to control when we have scroll in page

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Im using jquery datepicker in ascx page which and its has scroll.
It works fine in Chrome and IE 9 but not in IE11. We have enabled compatibility mode for our application. If i disable this mode then it works fine but other functions brakes.
I tried to forcefull set the top value in jquery but its not reflecting.

```
$('.clsFollowupDate').datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showWeek:true,
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    $(input).removeAttr("onblur");
    dataInp = input;
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').style.top($(this).offset().top+document.documentElement.scrollTop+"px !important"); 
 },
```

I can not disable the compatibility mode as its needed in other parts of application.

If i could display the calendar at the center of that screen also fine.but it should be shown at center with scroll as well.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: a working example could help us to fix your issue.

Comment: `We have enabled compatibility mode for our application. If i disable this mode then it works fine but other functions brakes` it sounds like you should be fixing that issue, not this one. You cannot expect all your users to run in compatibility mode as it's a crutch for standards compliance.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually its already in production and all user have this mode enabled.

Comment: @Vivek ...yikes. In that case I wish you the best of luck maintaining your system.